# What are some motivations that led to the development of the Lebesgue integral?

Tags: integration, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

There are many kinds of integrals, with the most famous being the Riemann integral which is taught in elementary calculus classes.

The motivation behind the Riemann integral is to find the area between curves by using rectangles of infinitely small width. When i first studied calculus, i was fascinated by this formulation and thought it was indeed ingenious.

My question is: what are the limitations of the riemann integral? What could be the link or the motivation to be able to "create" new ones like lebesgue, or darboux?

Comment: In fact to your first question, wikipedia has a section called "Limitations of the Riemann integral": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Limitations_of_the_Riemann_integral

Comment: It might be useful to instead start reading a book on measure theory (thus Lebesgue integration) to point out the problems with the Riemann integral. Long story short, Riemann integrals suck: They're clumsy to define, fail for entirely reasonable functions, don't extend nicely to more abstract spaces and don't behave as desired under limits and other operations. Stieltjes integrals are kind of a stepping stone between Riemannian and Lebesgue integrals, and Darboux integrals are just another formulation of the former. There are also more exotic and specific things like the Denjoy integral, etc.